# How to search Entities effectively in google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

I am using Datastore low level APIs for an application (Internal job portal).
I have an entity called **Candidate** with following properties

```
    Entity cadidate=new Entity("Candidate",getEmpNum());
    candidate.setProperty("name","some name");
    candidate.setProperty("skill","c++,Java,C#,GAE");
    candiate.setProperty("empNum");
```

The property 'skill' takes the a comma seperated string.  If an HR do a search for a candidate with a key
"GAE,Java"  , how do I effectively search for entities?
will the following query works?

```
    q.addFilter(searchBy, FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, searchFor);
    q.addFilter(searchBy, Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, searchFor+"Z");
```

If the above query works on say 1000 Entities ..does it work with same latency when there are 50,000 + entities in the datastore?

Please suggest me .. I am new to GAE and Datastore

-thanks
Ma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use list property.

```
List<String> skills = Arrays.asList("c++", "Java", "C#", "GAE");
candidate.setProperty("skill", skills);
```

then query with `IN` operator:

```
List<String> findSkills = Arrays.asList("Java","GAE");
q.addFilter("skill", FilterOperator.IN, findSkills);
```

This